# how to use one variable of an array type in more than one ngFor of different DIV or table in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display data that i get from an API,the problem comes when i try to use one array variable to more than one ngFor within one component, the response takes a lot of time to return or some times if i try to expand that response in a console it shows nothing. but if i delete one ngFor the response returns very fast. below are sample of my code.

sales.component.html

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 0;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="product-table d-block d-sm-none">
                <div class="product">
                    <ngb-accordion class="acc">

                        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let product of products">
                          <ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
                           <div class="d-flex">
                               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
                               <img src="../../assets/image/mac.svg" alt="">
                               <button ngbPanelToggle class=" accordion-button "><h5>{{product.name}}</h5></button>
                           </div>
                          </ng-template>
                          <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                            <div class="collapseinfo">
                                <h5>Category<span>{{product.category}}</span></h5>
                                <h5>Added date<span>{{product.last_update}}</span></h5>
                                <h5>Price<span>{{product.cost_price}}</span></h5>
                                <h5>Quantity<span>{{product.quantity}}</span></h5>
                            </div>
                          </ng-template>
                        </ngb-panel>
                      </ngb-accordion>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="product-desktop d-none d-sm-block">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product picture</th>
                            <th>product image</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Added date</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <tr *ngFor="let dproduct of products">  
                            <td><img src="../../assets/image/mac.svg" alt="Product 1"></td>
                            <td>{{dproduct.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{dproduct.category}}</td>
                            <td>{{dproduct.last_update}}</td>
                            <td>{{dproduct.cost_price}}</td>
                            <td>{{dproduct.quantity}}</td>                         
                        </tr>          
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sales.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sales',
  templateUrl: './sales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sales.component.scss']
})

export class SalesComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any;
  desktopproducts: any;
  url: any;
  

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let shopurl = '://abc.com/';
    let url = shopurl.split('//')[1].split('.')[0];
    let lastposition = url.lastIndexOf('-')
    let lasturl = url.substring(0, lastposition);
    this.url = lasturl;
    this.getproducts();
  }

  getproducts() {
    let producturl = `://${this.url}-admin.abc.com/api/items/`;
    return this.api.getData(producturl).subscribe({
      next: (products) => {
        let items = products;
        items.forEach((product:any) => {
           product.last_update = moment(product.last_update.split(' ')[0]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
         })
        this.products = items;

        console.log(this.products);
        

      }
    })
  }
  
}
```

api.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
 import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,public router: Router) { }

  opts={
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'abc-API-KEY':'abc@2020#'
    })
  }


  getData(url:any): Observable<any> {

    return this.httpClient.get(url, this.opts);

  }

}
```

Error from the console
[zone.js:1698 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#/product' is not a valid selector.
at getSelectorFromElement (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:26555:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement. (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEwfc.jpg)

Comment: due to that sometimes page become unresponsive

Comment: are you sure that the problem is the two *ngFor? BTW: you can use the same "loop variable" `product` in both loop and the src of the images **should** be `src="assets/image/mac.svg"` -remove the ../../-

Comment: Your template has nothing to do with the response time of an http request. If you check your network tab you will probably see that the response time is the same, what is causing slow down is probably the rendering of html. How many products are you retrieving? You may want to implement pagination or lazy loading instead of trying to render everything at once.

Comment: thanks @Eliseo  for your reply, am not sure if those two *ngFor will be the problem, but i believe so, because i'v been trying to create another component and copy each element one by one to the new component, and when i test, the problem comes after i paste the second *ngfor.

Comment: thanks brother @ChrisHamilton, i retrieve 500 product whenever i make an API call and also i'v been already try to implement pagination and yet the problem is still there, but there is an error that i get may be it might be a reason

1698 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#/product' is not a valid selector.
    at getSelectorFromElement (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:26555:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:28

Comment: Yes, trying to render that much at once is going to cause slow downs. Look into mechanisms to only render what is necessary: https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-ways-to-render-large-lists-in-angular-9f4dcb9b65

Comment: ok let me check on these rendering mechanism then i will let you know if i make any progress @ChrisHamilton

Comment: hi! @ChrisHamilton, i have succeeded to sort the problem and it was due to rendering large data as you have said before, so thanks a lot for your support